# How do you toggle UL list when the DIV is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I uniquely toggle the UL list when the the DIV is clicked? I am attempting to do the following, however I am getting an error with the toggle method.

Here is the code in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<style type="text/css">
.select:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul li {
    display: none;
}
ul li:before{ content:"- ";}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {

    $(".select").click(function() {
        $('ul').toggle();
    });


}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="select" id="numbers">Select Box1
    <ul>
        <li>1234</li>
        <li>5678</li>
        <li>0123</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="select" id="letters">Select Box2
    <ul>
        <li>abcd</li>
        <li>efgh</li>
        <li>ijkl</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="select" id="fruits">Select Box3
    <ul>
        <li>apples</li>
        <li>bananas</li>
        <li>oranges</li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed `$` before `('ul').toggle();` and you have to toggle `li` not `ul` because youe `li`s are hidden not `ul`.  Try like below.

```
$(".select").click(function () {
     $(this).find('ul li').toggle();
 });
```

Comment: Ok, ive corrected the code, but if the select div is clicked on, nothing else happens and the UL list is not displayed.

Comment: Ok this works, but toggles all 3 of the ULs how can I just toggle a single one?

Answer (score 1):

You should get the current `div` and using selector you can select all the  `li` element in  `ul` element as shown below

```
$(".select").click(function() {
    $(this).find('ul li').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(".select").click(function() {
        $('ul').toggle();
    });
```

You miss the $ before ul. Also I'd reference it by class or id instead of html tag. 
This code will reference all the UL in the page and not only the target one

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I jsut obtained the result:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  $(".select").click(function() {
    $('#' + this.id + ' > ul > li').toggle();
  });
}
```

```css
.select:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul li {
  display: none;
}
ul li:before{ content:"- ";}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>


<div class="select" id="numbers">Select Box1
    <ul>
        <li>1234</li>
        <li>5678</li>
        <li>0123</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="select" id="letters">Select Box2
    <ul>
        <li>abcd</li>
        <li>efgh</li>
        <li>ijkl</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="select" id="fruits">Select Box3
    <ul>
        <li>apples</li>
        <li>bananas</li>
        <li>oranges</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```